# How to show complete image in Navigation drawer background

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity, navigation-drawer

I have put an image in `Navigation Drawer` background. The image is there, but its not fitting the full image in the view,The upper part of the image around `5%` part of the image is not coming in the view, and thats the main part, i want it in  the background.

This is my code.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.myapp.HomeActivity"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout_main"
    >
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@drawable/sidebg"
        android:gravity="bottom|left"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        app:itemIconTint="@android:color/white"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        >

        <include layout="@layout/navigation_items"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Kindly guide me how to display complete image in navigation drawer background.

Comment: Have you tried adding `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` to `<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>`?

Comment: Just tired it, but no success

Comment: do you got it fixed ?

Comment: @RaguSwaminathan not yet

Comment: can you share the screenshot of what it looks like ?

Comment: Did you tried removing this line  android:fitsSystemWindows="true" from DrawerLayout?

Answer (score 0):

This is not an appropriate answer, but what you can do is reduce the size of the file and then apply

Comment: no code, you can change the size of the image in some editor and then apply.